# How to properly set index on Elasticsearch (5.2.0) in order to use transliteration and lemmatization?

Tags: elasticsearch, transliteration, lemmatization

I am trying to properly set index on Elasticsearch (V5.2.0) and to use the advantages of lemmatization. My index looks like this:

```
PUT /icu 
{
"settings":{
    "index":{
        "analysis":{
            "filter":{
                "latin_transform":{
                    "type":"icu_transform",
                    "id":"Any-Latin; Lower()"
                },
                "lemmagen_filter_sr":{
                    "type":"lemmagen",
                    "lexicon":"sr"
                }
            },
            "analyzer":{
                "lemmagen_lowercase_sr":{
                    "filter":[
                        "lemmagen_filter_sr",
                        "latin_transform"
                    ],
                    "type":"custom",
                    "tokenizer":"standard"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've installed https://github.com/vhyza/elasticsearch-analysis-lemmagen
but when I try to analyze something, It appears that If text is in Cyrillic it only apples **latin_transform** filter without **lemmagen_filter_sr**, and if text is latin, it applies **lemmagen_filter_sr** of words correctly.

Here is an example:

```
POST icu/_analyze
{  
    "analyzer":"lemmagen_lowercase_sr",
    "text":"реду раду и дисциплини redu i disciplini"
}
```

I receive the following:

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "redu",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 0
    },
    {
      "token": "radu",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 9,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "i",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 11,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "disciplini",
      "start_offset": 12,
      "end_offset": 22,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "red",
      "start_offset": 23,
      "end_offset": 27,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "i",
      "start_offset": 28,
      "end_offset": 29,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 5
    },
    {
      "token": "disciplina",
      "start_offset": 30,
      "end_offset": 40,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 6
    }
  ]
}
```

As can be seen, first four words have been transliterated to latin with no lemmatization applied, the last three words were originally latin scripted and lemmatization took place. How this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

After some tries I've found a workaround solution. Instead of using two filters in analyzer, I've moved latin_transform into char_filter, doing the transliteration via mapping first, and than applying lemmatization. new analyzer looks like this now:

```
"analysis":{
    "char_filter": {
        "latin_transform": {
            "type": "mapping",
            "mappings_path" : "serbian_mapping.txt"
        }
    },
    "filter":{
        "lemmagen_filter_sr":{
            "type":"lemmagen",
            "lexicon":"sr"
        }
    },
    "analyzer":{
        "lemmagen_lowercase_sr":{
            "filter":[
                "lemmagen_filter_sr",
                "lowercase"
            ],
            "char_filter": ["latin_transform"],
            "type":"custom",
            "tokenizer":"standard"
        }
    }
}
```

serbian_mapping.txt contains transliteration key pairs and that solves the issue.